# running npx with scoped packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I'm trying to execute a scoped package using npx. It seems like the only way to do it is specify the package directly, e.g.:

```
npx -p @foo/bar bar
```

Which will correctly download `@foo/bar` and run the `bar` entry in my `package.json` "bin" section:

```
"bin": {
    "bar": "./cli.js"
}
```

But, what I really want is to type this:

```
$ npx @foo/bar
npx: installed 1 in 4s
npx: command not found: bar
```

I've tried `@foo/bar`, `foo/bar`, `bar` in the `bin` section, no luck. Does npx support scoped packages like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, it looks like scoped packages work as long as you don't export any alternate commands. That is, you cannot use the object form and must instead specify only one bin command:

```
{
    "name": "@foo/bar",
    ...,
    "bin": "./cli.js"
}
```

Comment: Even when I have it set up this way, I'm getting `'bar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`